# Designing an event mechanism where an entity can be both listener (for some events) as well as generator (for some events) in C++

Tags: c++, oop, events, design-patterns, c++17

I am trying to create a basic design in c++ for an event mechanism which could have multiple event generators and listeners. The caveat here is that an object can behave as a listener (for some events) and a generator (for some other events). I am having a hard time figuring out the correct design for the same. Any suggestions please..

I initially thought of creating IListener and IGenerator interfaces which would be inherited by concrete/actual listeners and generators. However making a class inherit both interfaces doesn't seem kinda good design (not sure). Also, in addition to this, Could there be a way to restrict the generators to send only specific types of events from the event list (enums).?

Comment: In the end an event mechanism (without threading/decoupling) is just a list of callback functions of a given function signature e.g. `std::vector<void()`> and calling the events is nothing more then going over that list. Put that in a class and aggregate where needed. A listener passes such a function on to a generator. If the generator can "forward" events it again has a list of listeners. And it can register one of its members to handle an event and call its own list of listeners.

Comment: As a listener your class should implement as many `IAbcListener` interfaces as needed. Also it should implement as many `RegisterListener` overloads as needed and as many `NotifyAbc` as needed

Comment: I suggest you work with composition: The main object can contain multiple listeners and generators. The callback invoked by a listener could be an arbitrary ```std::function``` that can refer back to the parent object